# django q object condition matching

Tags: django, django-q

my question is when i select datefrom and dateto it showing error ."Key 'gender' not found in

now even i used the Q object still same problem as earlier..

```
search_gender = request.POST["gender"]
age_from = request.POST["age_from"]
age_to = request.POST["age_to"]
date_from = request.POST["date_from"]
date_to = request.POST["date_to"]

if date_from:
    date_from = datetime.strptime(request.POST["date_from"],"%d %B %Y")

if date_to:
    date_to = datetime.strptime(request.POST["date_to"],"%d %B %Y")

patient = PatientInfo()

p_male = 0
p_female = 0
age1 = 0
age2 = 0
date1 = 0
date2 = 0

if search_gender == 'male' :
    p_male = 1
if search_gender == 'female' :
    p_female = 1

if age_from:
    age1 = 1
if age_to:
    age2 = 1
if date_from:
    date1 = 1
if date_to:
    date2 = 1

if date1 and date2:
    patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(
            Q(dateedit__range = (date_from,date_to))
            )
```

still showing error when I select date_from and date_to both ??? not getting exactly even I neither select male nor female even I used if request.POST.has_key('gender') still error 
and I am new to django.. plz help... thanx in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The error you reported is raised when a dictionary lookup is attempted for a key that doesn't exist in that dictionary -- pretty much exactly what the error is telling you.

Since all I have to go on is the code you posted, my guess would be that for whatever reason "gender" is not actually present in the request.POST dictionary. You need to find out why.

In general, when dealing with dictionaries, the best practice is to either check for the presence of the key first or use the `dict.get` method to provide a fallback:

```
# Check for dictionary key
if request.POST.has_key('gender'):
    gender = request.POST['gender']

# or Provide fallback
gender = request.POST.get('gender', 'male') # if gender isn't present, 'male' will be returned
```

Answer (score 0):

For this a form would be very usefull!

Something like:

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    GENDERS = (
        ('m','Male'),
        ('f', 'Female')
    )
    gender    = forms.CharField(choices=GENDERS, required=False)
    age_from  = forms.IntegerField()
    age_to    = forms.IntegerField()
    date_from = request.POST["date_from"]
    date_to   = forms.DateTimeField()


    def clean_gender(self):
        gender = self.cleanded_data.get('gender', 'm')

        #do something with gender

        return gender#now it has always a value
```

views.py:

```
def myform(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        gender = form.cleaned_data.get('gender')

        #do something with data...


else:
    form = MyForm()

return render_to_response('template.html', {'form':from})
```